# html5 capturing mouse clicks in a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Here is simplified code that takes into account the answer suggested by nycnik.  The code works better, but the scale and offset are still off.  Click drag and release, and the line drawn appears to be approximately a factor of 2 off.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="st.css" media="all"/>
    <script>
var x, y;
function getXY(canvas, e) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    return [e.clientX - rect.left, e.clientY - rect.top];
}

function move(ca, e) {


}

function mark(ca, e) {
    [x,y] = getXY(ca, e);
}

function clickDrag(ca, e) {
    var c = ca.getContext("2d");
    var x2, y2;
    [x2,y2] = getXY(ca, e);
    c.fillStyle='#00FF80';
    c.lineStyle='#FFFF80';
    c.moveTo(x,y);
    c.lineTo(x2,y2);
    c.stroke();  
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="bg">
      <canvas id="q13g" onmousedown="mark(this,event)" onmouseup="clickDrag(this, event)">
      </canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to convert using clientX, that you saw, and the bounding rectangle, as seen below, and in this tutorial:

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
        var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
          x: evt.clientX - rect.left,
          y: evt.clientY - rect.top
        };
      }
```

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-mouse-coordinates/

Comment: This seems to have fixed the offset, but not the scale.  The coordinates still seem scaled by more than 2:1

Comment: As Ken said below, that scale has to do with sizing of the canvas.  Your code did not show any canvas resizing